Stripe subscriptionURL is returning a 404 and i cant figure out next steps - Nextjs 14, Supabase, prisma, stripe
i'm a newish coder and i've hit a wall and would appreciate any help on next steps. I'm following this youtube tutorial - https://youtu.be/5dgYg10B9p0?si=2sEfymmFw_i6Qr0b and stuck at the 2:38:00 mark. When i hit create subscription i'm getting redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/createSubscription
I've manually typed the code a couple of times, i've copied his code for the various pages/files,console log, verified versions, and i've gone to stripes dev docs and have no luck. In terms of the dev docs, i'm not really seeing what he is using (npm install of stripe) as the instructions are different. all of the other functionality of creating a customer in stripe, db tables existing/linked seem to be working. i tried searching online (here, similar youtube vid's, stripe docs, prisma docs, etc) but i'm mostly finding webhook related guides or what appears to be vastly different implementations. Not sure i'm searching for the right terms.
Expectation: When i click the subscribe button i'm redirected to the stripe payment screen.
Actual:  get redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/createSubscription w/ a 404
his repo:  https://github.com/ski043/Marshal-Saas/blob/981f51dd474b648bc9dc0f60e5a4c26f963377a7/app/dashboard/billing/page.tsx
console log: Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/createSubscription?
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
code:
billing page:
import { Card, CardContent } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { CheckCircle2 } from "lucide-react";
import prisma from "@/app/lib/db";
import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { getStripeSession, stripe } from "@/app/lib/stripe";
import { StripeSubscriptionCreationButton } from "@/app/components/Submitbuttons";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const featureItems = [
  { name: "Lorem Ipsum something" },
  { name: "Lorem Ipsum something" },
  { name: "Lorem Ipsum something" },
  { name: "Lorem Ipsum something" },
  { name: "Lorem Ipsum something" },
];

async function getData(userId: string) {
  const data = await prisma.subscription.findUnique({
    where: {
      userId: userId,
    },
    select: {
      status: true,
      user: {
        select: {
          stripeCustomerId: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  return data;
}

export default async function BillingPage() {
  const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
  const user = await getUser();
  const data = await getData(user?.id as string);

  async function createSubscription() {
    "use server";

    const dbUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: user?.id,
      },
      select: {
        stripeCustomerId: true,
      },
    });

    if (!dbUser?.stripeCustomerId) {
      throw new Error("Unable to get customer id");
    }

    const subscriptionUrl = await getStripeSession({
      customerId: dbUser.stripeCustomerId,
      domainUrl: "http://localhost:3000",
      priceId: process.env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID as string,
    });

    return redirect(subscriptionUrl);
  }

  return (
    <div className="max-w-md mx-auto-space-y-4">
      <Card className="flex flex-col">
        <CardContent className="py-8">
          <div>
            <h3 className="inline-flex px-4 py-1 rounded-full text-sm font-semibold tracking-wide uppercase bg-primary/10 text-primary">
              Monthly
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-4 flex items-baseline text-6xl font-extrabold">
            $30 <span className="ml-1 text-2xl text-muted-foreground">/mo</span>
          </div>
          <p className="mt-5 text-lg text-muted-foreground">
            Explore as many business ideas as you want for $30 a month!
          </p>
        </CardContent>
        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col justify-between px-6 pt-6 pb-8 bg-secondary rounded-lg m-1 space-y-6 sm:p-10 sm:pt-6">
          <ul className="space-y-4">
            {featureItems.map((item, index) => (
              <li key={index} className="flex items-centered">
                <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                  <CheckCircle2 className="h-6 w-6 text-green-500" />
                </div>
                <p className="ml-3 text-base">{item.name}</p>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>

          <form className="w-full" action="createSubscription">
            <StripeSubscriptionCreationButton />
          </form>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}


It looks like your local server at http://localhost:3000/dashboard/createSubscription isn't accessible yet, because it is returning 404. You would want to aim for being able to send a request to this URL with a 200 response code first, before thinking of redirecting to Stripe's Checkout page. It's NextJS routing configuration.
